# Skype for Business - (custom) presence should not change after locking screen

Tags: lync, skype-for-business

I want to avoid that Skype for Business (Lync) is changing also my custom status to "away" after locking the screen. Is there any way to adjust the ([Script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Set-CsCustomPresenceps1-in-8c78d094)) from that website in a way that an additional registry entry is modified?

Just let me know if you need some more details.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to stop this behaviour.

Remember Lync is a softphone, if the machine is locked it, Lync assumed you can't answer the phone, so it sets the presence to indicate that you are most unlikely to answer the phone (or reply to a message in general).

If you really want it to not want to change, you can:

- Stop machine from going into the locked state
- Run another lync client that will not go into the locked state
- Use a UCMA application (untrusted or trusted) to publish the presence for that user to "force" the current overall presence to what you want.

I would personally think that you will just have to live with this behaviour.

Comment: Hi,
thanks for your reply. Seems that the second option (tried pidgin) is only showing the expected result with less effort. Unfortunately it comes with other challenges :(